# compiling Linux kernel 3.10.10 with GRSecurity patch

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm having a problem compiling the Linux kernel 3.10.10 with GRSecurity patch
under Lubuntu 13.04

These are the commands I use to compile:

```
make-kpkg clean
make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version "grsec" kernel_image
```

All is working fine, until this error message is shown:

```
[...]
  AS      arch/x86/lib/putuser.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/rwlock.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/rwsem.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/string_32.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/strstr_32.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/thunk_32.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/usercopy.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/usercopy_32.o
  AR      arch/x86/lib/lib.a
  LINK    vmlinux
  LD      vmlinux.o
ld: final link failed: Memory exhausted
make[1]: *** [vmlinux] Fehler 1
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/usr/src/linux/linux-3.10.10'
make: *** [debian/stamp/build/kernel] Fehler 2
```

I found several tips that didn't help so far.
Increasing the RAM to 4 GB lead to the same error.

Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks for your advise.

---

System:
Lubuntu 13.04
2GB RAM, 40 GB HD

Comment: I'd wager that you need more memory.  How do you know 4GB is sufficient?

Comment: I logged the amount of RAM everv second into a file while compiling, it never got over 500 MB

Comment: did you ever fix this? I'm having this same problem at the same point in my  kernel build process.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue while compiling kernel 3.19.0. I was running from inside an ubuntu VM with 512MB RAM and stack size of 8192KB. I increased my stack size to unlimited by following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169035/9759). And then increased my VM size to 4GB (increasing the stack size limit alone didn't fix things). With both those changes my build finished successfully.